# Only changing title background color without affecting any properties of other controls (android)

Tags: android, background, themes, custom-titlebar

I have designed a custom theme , because I wanted to change title background color.
However while designing the theme, I have set android:parent="android:Theme.Light"

After doing this, I found out that properties of progressbar control, alertdialog, tabhost have changed like background color, height , width,etc.

It was working fine when I was not using the custom theme.

So my question is how to use the properties of android default theme while only changing the title background color.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Once You have build the Theme for the `Title`
you can use this `Custom Theme` in `AndroidManifest.xml` in ypur Activity Tag

like

```
android:theme="@style/customTheme"
```

Comment: I did the same before and its running well, but its changing the properties of other control like tabhost, alertbox, progressbar.

Comment: It Should not change the properties of the following list  try it again

Comment: you have changed the android:parent="android:Theme.Light" but i am changing the theme only try it again